# Qt LGPL license exception?

Tags: qt, licensing, lgpl

I'm using the [Qt/Mfc Migration Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/index.html) to begin to convert some UI code from MFC to Qt. I'm wondering whether I absolutely have to keep the Qt migration code in a seperate library or if it would be possible to include it in my project. In order to do that, I would have to modify it slightly (add #include "stdafx.h" for example and change some other include paths). The Qt LGPL exception, which is also used for the migration framework, reads:

> Nokia Qt LGPL Exception version 1.0
>
> As a special exception to the GNU Lesser General Public License
>   version 2.1, the object code form of a "work that uses the Library"
>   may incorporate material from a header file that is part of the
>   Library.  You may distribute such object code under terms of your
>   choice, provided that the incorporated material (i) does not exceed
>   more than 5% of the total size of the Library; and (ii) is limited to
>   numerical parameters, data structure layouts, accessors, macros,
>   inline functions and templates.

Would I trigger the license or am I still in the green?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either I'm misunderstanding what you want to do, or you clearly aren't allowed to do it.

You say you want to "include the Qt code in my project", which implies you want to link the whole of their library (or all the pieces you're using) into your own module, rather than keeping it in a separate DLL.

But the terms say you can "incorporate material from a *header file*" (my emphasis) *not* the main library.

And they say "provided that the incorporated material (i) does not exceed more than 5% of the total size of the Library", *not* the whole library.

And they say "limited to numerical parameters, data structure layouts, accessors, macros, inline functions and templates", *not* any of the main code of the library.

Seems blatantly obvious to me, but have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Well, I am just talking about the MFC/Qt migration code, which is like 8 files. But I guess you are still right. They aren't just header files and I suppose they are not limited to numerical parameters, etc.

Comment: The `LGPL` allows you to modify headers, and the exception **version `1.0`** allows you to use `inline functions and templates`, So, you can inline `5%` into headers and dynamic-link to what remains (if anything else is used). **But unfortunately**, they fixed this in **version `1.1`** of the exception, too bad (but you could like me: stick to old lib-sources and license, then update whatever required manually).

Answer (score 1):

Any component of the Qt solutions must be built as a DLL if you want to use it under LGPL terms. It doesn't matter whether you modify it or not.